# Xcode Interfacebuilder bug?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I got a problem in the Xcode project.

below image shown UITabbar problem. I thought it's a Interface builder bugs.

UITabbar showing a dark color. That only shown a root & one-depth ViewController.

How can I solve it?

Thanks.

[image]

## == Modified ==

The problem suddenly appeared.

It is not known whether the problem is caused what.

TabbarItem area is like a shown bug as image.

I hope Tabbar area to be displayed correctly.

I tried to various way to solve the problem.
tried ways as a below :

1. regenerate xcode project and then copy storyboard. => fail
2. regenerate storyboard and then copy partial elements in storyboard. => fail
3. regenerate all of them. => I did not try yet.(have too much elements. I want to avoid like this way.)

Interest point is sometimes display correctly. When I first open a simple storyboard file(Default UITabbar Project's main storyboard) like a below image.

it bring to me confused.

Comment: What are we looking at here? Where is the problem supposed to be? Can you add some more detail?

Comment: I modified a question. Give thanks to the interest.

Comment: Have you assigned any custom images to the tab bar items? The shadow looks like an image with incorrect height width ratio...

Comment: I doesn't assigned any images. It was solved to assign images! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that helped. It will be great if you can mark my answer as right answer since that may help more people having similar problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize what I know about storyboard that may cause similar issue...

- Assigning images that have incompatible width:height ratios to tab
  bar items
- Not assigning any images or not using any system images for tab bar
  items

Hope this can help anyone else that has similar issues...